# How to use a CDN with Play Framework 2.4 Assets?

Tags: playframework, cdn, playframework-2.4

I'd like to use a CDN URL that is automatically added to the Asset URL when getting assets via:

```
@routes.Assets.versioned("js/whatever.js")
```

There's a [great article on how to setup a CDN URL for Play 2.3](http://www.jamesward.com/2014/04/29/optimizing-static-asset-loading-with-play-framework), but I cannot find any examples of how to do it in Play 2.4. Has anyone already figured this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what caching strategy your web infrastructure needs.

Speaking of 2.3 to 2.4 transition there's just one thing you need to change:

- use `controller` instead of `object`

See the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24) for the why on that.

On a more general note, Play framework has excellent [caching support](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets) built in. I'd use `versioned` instead of `at` with the built-in `Assets` controller to include versioning support through using [Etag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag). It is worth checking whether your CDN supports Etag.

You can use either or both of this HTTP header-based Etag technique and the filename-based technique from the blog post. It depends on your web infrastructure. One may be better than other.

(P.S. code in that blog wouldn't compile, the custom `at` expects three parameters and the call to it has just two parameters.)

Comment: Thanks, I definitely want to utilize the Etag functionality, but I also need to support users from all over the country and would like to use a CDN combined with the Play caching features if possible. It looks like a reverse proxy CDN would be able to accomplish this.

Comment: Akamai CDN had some kind of reverse proxy when I used that at Sky, however their UI/config for it was terrible. I'd use a separate reverse proxy (e.g., Nginx) and get the CDN to use that instead.

Comment: @bjfletcher I know this is old, but I have a fundamental question on this. When we are adding the CDN host at the Play application level, every asset request has to come to Play first and then go to CDN correct? If so, how are we benefitting from CDN?

Comment: In our case.. we don't use Play way of UI.. we use Angular 2 with webpack. So I think, we will try webpack configuration for the CDN. Thanks!